# Devcrypto Openssl on Openwrt

Tags: openwrt

On my wrt1900acs on Openwrt I use openssl devcrypto with success.

```
root@hawk:~# openssl engine -t -c
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
     [ unavailable ]
(devcrypto) /dev/crypto engine
 [DES-CBC, DES-EDE3-CBC, AES-128-CBC, AES-192-CBC, AES-256-CBC, AES-128-ECB, AES-192-ECB, AES-256-ECB]
     [ available ]
```

But with my netgear R7800 nss driver with the same config in my build (.config) i don't have the same output :

```
root@hawk:~# openssl engine -t -c
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
     [ unavailable ]
(devcrypto) /dev/crypto engine
     [ available ]
```

Do you have an idea?

And someone said to me about asm accelerator, but I don't know about it, is it enable by default? How to see if it Working?

> ASM optimized crypto code in openssl is faster compared to using crypto dev in openssl.

And finaly, I've read on "afalg"
But not sure how it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is likely that the devcrypto module isn't available. It is not available by default. Or, if it is available, doesn't have any backing drivers.

This comes from the `kmod-cryptodev` package. That is just the interface though, there is additionally an actual crypto driver that is hardware-specific that will power that interface. `cat /proc/crypto` on the working device to see the driver name. It is likely that *that* driver is compiled into the kernel by default (not a module). I think on this platform the module is called `qca_nss_drv`?

Additionally you need `libopenssl-devcrypto` package to be the user-space component that interacts with that kernel interface. It looks like you have that already?